# Natural language processing API for iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, nlp

I am looking for NLP capable library or API which will be able to identify number, date, person, place name, and parts of speech from a given sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSLinguisticTagger](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will do this. Introduced in iOS 5.

Comment: later on i used this, but i forgot to post it as an answer. Thanks it will really help others

Answer (score 1):

You should try Nuance SDK for iOS. You also can try CMU (open source) but quality is pretty low, especially for conditions with noisy environments.

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/

Comment: i think that sdk is for proccesing voice dictation not for natural language processing

Comment: http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home

Comment: From your question tt seems like you need speech recognition.

Comment: If I had more time I would write one! This would actually be a worthwhile effort on someone's part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for named entity recognition. You could use Boost Spirit for parsing.